# Looking for a time travel TV series with champagne that apparently bubbled down

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am looking for a TV series I saw around 2000-2005.

I believe it was about a secret organisation sending people in the past to prevent a disaster. I remember at the end of the episode, they were celebrating another successful mission - that person 5th or 10th - which was rare because all the other people sent before became insane after only 2 or 3 missions.

I do remember it because the main character was looking at a champagne glass, but the bubbles were going down, implying that mental health was degrading.

Comment: [Seven Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Days_(TV_series)) fits the time frame, but not the insanity bit.

Comment: I remember the episode, it is Seven Days @Machavity.  Give me a bit and I'll find the reference.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is the UPN series [Seven Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Days_(TV_series)), and the champagne glass bit specifically comes from the episode *Deja Vu All Over Again* in Season 2.

- The show as a whole is about a program that sends someone into the past to prevent a disaster.
- There is only one pilot, Frank Parker, that's able to consistently pilot the time machine because of the pain tolerances required (it's alien tech, and severely duct taped, and never ever actually portrayed as something safe or wise for them to be playing with).  Problem is, this pilot has had mental breakdowns in the past, so higher ups tend to treat him like a liability at best, or ticking bomb at worst.
- The episode you reference with the "backwards bubbles" actually has Frank experiencing glitches of fragmented and backwards time.  Few take him seriously and just presume he's having mental glitches.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The opening credits brought back some memories, and apparently the champagne glass was only beer :)